# Which Data compression algorithm has been used in WinRar?

Tags: algorithm, audio, video, compression, lossless-compression

Which compression algorithm is used in WinRar? I am working on file compression techniques. So which algorithm will be best for compression of audio/video files?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR): "It is one of the few applications that is able to create RAR archives natively, because the encoding method is held to be proprietary."See also [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compression algorithm of WinRar is proprietary.

For common data compression, 7zip performs better than WinRar.

However, for audio/video files, common data compression techniques like zip, winrar, 7zip have poor performance. You should use specific audio compression techniques like aac, amr, ogg, and specific video compression techniques like h.264, mpeg-4, etc. These specific audio/video compression techniques are lossy, thus gain much more compression ratio than lossless techniques like zip/winrar/7zip.

From the perspective of Information Theory, which founded by Shannon, the distribution of common data, audio data and video data are completely different, thus the proper compression techniques are different.

Comment: Does AAC, AMR and ogg work only on audio/video or on any data?

Comment: aac, amr,ogg only work on audio, and h.264, mpeg-4 only work on video.

Comment: You should also mention that zip, rar, etc are loseless and that's why they are poor for audio and video compression when compared to lossy compression methods like mpeg, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should mention it.